# Транзакции в Django

Tags: django, postgresql, транзакции

У меня есть следующая функция:

```
def save_awards(awards, instance):
    for award in awards:
        _award = Award.objects.create( # 3
            name=award['name'],
            type=AwardType.objects.get(pk=award['type']),
            child=instance,
        )
        save_attachments_to_instance(
            validated_attachments_ids_list=award['attachments'],
            instance=_award,
        )
```

Все, что она делает - создает и тут же сохраняет объект достижения `award` и вызывает функцию `save_attachments_to_instance` которая прикрепляет к созданному `award` другие объекты.

Функция `save_attachments_to_instance`:

```
def save_attachments_to_instance(validated_attachments_ids_list, instance, check_already_attached=True):
    validated_attachments_ids_list = list(set([int(_) for _ in validated_attachments_ids_list]))

    # Отвязка
    attached = Attachment.objects.filter(
        object_id=instance.id,
    )
    attached.update(
        object_id=None,
        content_type_id=None,
    )

    # Привязка
    attachments = Attachment.objects.filter(
        id__in=validated_attachments_ids_list,
    )

    errors = dict()
    if check_already_attached:
        for attachment in attachments:
            if attachment.content_object and attachment.content_object != instance:
                errors[attachment.id] = 'Already attached to another instance. Detach first.'

    if errors:
        raise drf_exceptions.ValidationError({
            'attachments': errors,
        })
    else:
        for at in attachments:
            at.content_object = instance
            at.save()
```

Я хочу, чтобы если вдруг где-то произошла ошибка (выбросилось исключение) - удалились все созданные `awards` и произошла отвязка `attachments` (attachments уже существуют на этапе создания `award`, удалять их ненужно).

Можно ли это реализовать без лишних танцев с бубном и велосипедов? Гугл привел [в документацию](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/transactions/), но у меня не завелось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@transaction.atomic
def save_awards(awards, instance):
    ...
```

Comment: Спасибо, проверил! Не думал, что так просто..